# GUI locks itself with StartOnMainThread

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm using JavaApplicationBundle to set icon for my jar file, and now I am trying to remove my program from Dock.

I've set `LSUIElement` to 1, but that didn't worked until I added `StartOnMainThread` directive in Java section of Info.plist.

But - then problem appeared - GUI was locked up - just like the program is executing infinite loop or something. I've changed `main()` to be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread queryThread = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                new MainWindow();
              }
            };
            queryThread.start();
        }
```

but I can't see the JDialog - it won't appear even if the JavaApplicationBundle process is running (as this is background application now - could there be some step that I am missing to bring up the dialog?)

What can cause this problem? Does anybody have simple app bundle where java program is running without sitting in Dock - I've searched internet, but nothing appeared in my search results?

Thanks

**Edit**

After reading comments, I've tried what I already tried, but I forgot about it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run() {
                new MainWindow();
      }
    });
}
```

In this case, application is running - but no GUI is shown. When I check Console Messages I see few of these:

```
*** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSCOnditionLock: 0x1347a0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
*** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
```

Comment: Make sure your starting the GUI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Check with the use of EventQueue.isDispatchingThread

Comment: As far as I know, Swing/AWT app **must not** use `startOnFirstThread` because the Event Dispatch Thread must run on the first thread, and not your `main` method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've changed code to `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
            new MainWindow();
     }
   });`, but I got few `Break on _NSLockError() to debug` messages in Console.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, if I don't set StartOnMainThread, my application is always sticking itself to the Dock - completely ignoring `LSUIElement` attribute. I will read more about it, thank you for pointing me in this direction.